# WCF app . Structure map Objectfactory losing instance of an Object

Tags: wcf, structuremap

I am trying to get WCF work with Structuremap. I took most of the code from Jimmy Bogard's blog 
[Integrating StructureMap with WCF](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2008/07/30/integrating-structuremap-with-wcf/)

I am reusing all my objects (Domain, NHIBERNATE ,  Service layer ) that was created for ASP.nET MVC application.I have a separate IoC Library where I bootstrap all regisrties

I have added global.asax and in Application Start Event this is what I have :

```
var webServiceRegistry = new WebServiceRegistry();
var bootStrapper = new IoC.BootStrapper();
bootStrapper.Start();
```

WebServiceRegistry is a normal class and in its constructor I have the following:

```
 var appUser = new AppUser
            {
                Role = userDto.Role,
                Email = userDto.Email,
                Id = userDto.Id,
                CompanyName = dealerDto.Name,
                Name = userDto.Name,
                IsImpersonated = false,
                Impersonater = Guid.Empty
            };
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User = appUser;
            ObjectFactory.Configure(x => x.For<IAppUser>().Use(appUser));
```

**Everything goes fine - no errors** 

<strike>Things start to **fail** when my my wcf service class is being instantiated which has a Domainservice object (IDomainServiceObject domainServiceObject) in constructor with 202 error.</strike>

The failure is in DomainService Registry where it fails to get default instance of **IAppUser**

**Edit**

Initial problem was in that I had error in constructor of StructureMapServiceHost.

Now I dont get any error  but I am not getting the instance of IAppUser that I inject. In place of that it creates a new instance of AppUser.

Do anyone have a clue as to why this happens?

I have tried adding HttpContextScope , HybridHttpOrThreadLocalScoped and still same result

I have conformed that at the time all registries are called in bootstrapper IAppUser instance is the once that was provided with values in it (and not created by StructureMap)
In Application Start it does create the whole graph .

As soon as it enters webmethod ILMSUser is a new instance.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want the same object back every time you can use singleton

```
this.For<IAppUser>().Singleton().Use(appUser);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing to right instance Lifetime creator. Any idea why my initial code dont work even if I create and add instance in Begin Request event?

Comment: Sorry I have no idea. There should be no need to add specific instances into the container (at least I haven't done that ever). Usually it has been enough that I configure the container once and use HttpContextScoped() for those objects that need to have lifetime of single request. In the EndRequest I call ObjcetFactory.ReleaseAndDisposeAllHttpScopedObjects().